Could not find implementation 'com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.140.0' during build
I wanted to test old apllication but i had to

change build gradle to
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
change the gradle wraper property to
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-bin.zip

When a can back to the new application how was working for years now. I got problem with dependencies at build time.
the following library have desapear from my application and i cannont get them bach from depedencie.
here are the library
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/vr/sdk-controller/1.140.0/sdk-controller-1.140.0.aar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/vr/sdk-base/1.140.0/sdk-base-1.140.0.aar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/vr/sdk-common/1.140.0/sdk-common-1.140.0.aar
I had a look at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/ and "vr" does not exist anymore.
Very strange ....
Hopefully i got all the library saved.
It is possible to add those library directly to my application so do not need maven anymore for the build.
I have tried to rebuild the original project "gvr-android-sdk-1.140.0" from google but the same problem appear at build time the depedencie are not found.
How it is possible that uodatinf gradle version on one project produce error to some other.
thanks for your help.

It loock like google have removed those depedencies from maven. Is there a way to get it from somewhere else ?. I try to use the library aar that i got got always missing some string value wich must be in the depedencie from maven. What can i do ?

The problem is not the missing depdencie in Maven but that the build of VR project do not find anymore the depedencie that i downloader yers ago to run VR project. Changing gradle distribution to old project to the same that VR project put the mess in depedencie build.

i can compile using aar library but i stil got error. :app:processDebugResourcesAGPBI: resource string/gvr_vr_mode_component.

Please note that JCenter has been sunset and is no longer available. The com.google.vr:sdk-base and com.google.vr:sdk-controller libraries are managed by Google and appear to be available on Google’s registry under https://chromium.googlesource.com. You may get them by following this link.

thanks Elinaf. But how to retreive those depedencies from gardle.build in android studio.

Hi and thanks for the helper.
I found out how to solve the problem. I fact it was very easy.

i copied the full directory containing the aar and pom to under APP directory.
I had command line to the build.gradle(:app)
dependencies
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.aar'], dir: 'libraries')

Library must be copied under app directory not under the project directory.
That's all
So nothing to see with gradle.
