what can be done if dependancies are removed from maven
I found out that the com.google.vr dependencies has been removed from maven. It was used for virtual réality on android.
Does some one kronw how to find those dependencies or does someone have a copy of thoses depedencies.
I am looking for:
com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.140.0

com.google.vr:sdk-controller:1.140.0


Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78888986/927493

Hm.. what do you mean by com.google.vr has been removed from Maven? It was never a part of Maven...

com.google.vr wasn't removed, the whole repository JCenter was shut down and the other repos are not up o date or require a user account.   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.vr/sdk-base

thanks Robert. But how do i retreive these depedencie using gardle.build in android studio.
